# Get 2KV AC 15AMP draw from 2 lines of 220

Tags: electrical-engineering

How would I go by getting around 2KV ac rms able to support an average current of 15amp and max of 20amp out of 2 lines of 220? And what kind of relay could take that? Looking for a winding ratio.

Comment: Relay or transformer? have you considered that power in = power out?

Comment: I’m just looking for a wind ratio for 2 lines of 220vac 50amp to ~2KV 10amp.

Comment: Then you should add that to your question.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get 2kV from a relay unless you have 2kV available.

Transformer.

$$Turns\ ratio = \frac {V_{High}} {V_{Low}}$$

Comment: I know . I’m just wondering what kind of relay takes that.

Comment: Usually a low voltage relay switches a high voltage load.  So your relay concept does not make sense.

Comment: Im not super experienced in electronics but I figure switching something like that directly would not be a good idea in terms of arcing.

Comment: This is power.  To switch it, you have to have it.  And yes it is not a good idea.  But 220V:2000V is a step-up transformer and it is valid and not inherently dangerous.

Comment: 220vac in parallel with a 1:4.5 turn ratio should give me close to what I want at least I think.

Comment: You are scaring me.  9:1 turn ratio from 220V gives 1980V.

Comment: 220vac in parallel should give me 440vac